# 'S' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I have import git project, everything is perfect but it appearing while running in physical device.
I have tried to change file name as android studio guide,

I have tried to change file name as android studio guide,
I have open resource then drawable and select image name and then change
but still it say, please change your file name.
I also tried to change format jpg to png and others

Comment: You have to use all lower case letters in your resource files. If its still giving you problems after changing it, you're changing the wrong resource